# Why is event.preventDefault(); not stopping my page from refreshing?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to create a to-do list, so I created a button that would log down whatever it is the user writes. However, when you click the button it refreshes the page. Why isn't `event.preventDefault()`; stopping the refresh of the page when you click the button?

```js
// Selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

//Event Listeners
todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

//Functions

function addTodo(event) {
  // Prevent from submitting
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<header>
  <h1>Kevin's To Do List</h1>
</header>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input">
  <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
  </button>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the relevant html

Comment: Show the relevant HTML.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the HTML Document that contains the `.todo-input`, `.todo-button`, and `.todo-list` elements, along with any other relevant portions of the document?

Comment: It’s cleaner to listen for the `submit` event of the form instead of the `click` event of the button, but it should still work…

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: clicking the button in your posted snippet _does not_ cause any `<form>` submission for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem in my life earlier and I tried bubbling and cancelling and preventing default and everything until I came across this.

You put an event listener on the form itself so that when it the user submits, instead of just "POST"ing or "GET"ing, it runs a function which checks the form and if it is okay, it returns true, otherwise false.

You can go "onsubmit='return false;'" and it will never "POST" but you can also return the output of a function.

For form checking and more secure transmission of form data I use something like the following.

```
function conditionalFormSubmit(){
    var form=document.getElementById('formID'); 
        if (checkForm(form)){
            form.submit();
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

And in the html I say

```
<form id='formID'
   onsubmit='return conditionalFormSubmit();'>
    <input name='data' value'some form data' /> 
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

This is the means by which I can check and alter the form data prior to submission.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

just use your js code inside body and after your html code fix your issue
i didn't add code to snnipet to better read:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here, you can insert data in input then show output in li element.

```js
// Selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

//Event Listeners
todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

//Functions
function addTodo(event) {
    // Prevent from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    if (todoInput.value.trim() != '' && todoInput.value.trim() != null){
        var li = document.createElement("li")
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todoInput.value));
        todoList.appendChild(li);
    }
    todoInput.value = '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
</head>


<h1>Kevin's To Do List</h1>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input">
  <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
  </button>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list">
  </ul>
</div>
```